# I can't place objects in div's in the same line

Tags: html, css

Here is the html code that I work on.

```
<div id="menu">
    <center>
        <div style="list-style: none; class:" menu ">
            <div style="display: inline "><a href="indeks.html " class="button ">Home</a> </div>
            <div style="display: inline "><a href="indeks.html " class="button ">Repertuar</a> </div>
        </div> 
    </center> 
</div>
```

And here is the css part

```
#menu {
    margin:20px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: right;
}
.button {
    display : block;
    background: #ff0080;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ff0080, #ffb248);
    height: 50pxx;
    width : 100px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border : 2px solid rgba(33, 68, 72, 0.59);
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I tried literaly lots of ways, searched loads of tutorials, and even digged in some sites source codes but for some reason 2 buttons that i made always display themselves one under another instead of being next to eachother.

Im trying to make a menu, and it seems that i screwed something, and i cant even find what (problems of learning in other language than your own).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You screwed the HTML  :)

Replace

```
<div style="list-style: none; class:"menu">    <!-- wrong -->
```

with:

```
<div style="list-style: none;" class="menu">   <!-- Correct -->
```

#### And also:

- Don't use `center` tag as it is deprecated.
- To get the buttons on same line, use `display: inline-block` instead of `display: inline`
- Avoid using inline styling as you are already using css classes. This helps you to keep the css code in structure.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lsxhdmdu/2/)**

Comment: class:"menu"? Do you mean class="menu"?

Comment: @miny1997 the first line of code is the correct one. I think my explanation is confusing right?

Comment: I thinked the first line of code was your proposition. My error.

Comment: you say that <center> is deprecated but what should i use then

Comment: @user3015184 `text-align: center` in css.. check the above fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i already fixed this (and i noticed that i suck at logic) .
All this time i waswriting that my site should display my menus inline and buttons in block (because im a genius ).

Anyway thanks for everyone who looked at it but im just that stupid sometimes.

Comment: You are posting a comment as an **answer**. Instead, please accept a answer which helped you. :)

Comment: Because i solved it myself before anyone answered (Week of searching the web and asking my freinds on how to do this. And i found by myself just when i asked ... irony)

Answer (score 0):

Change your .button class css with this :

```
.button {
    background: #ff0080;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ff0080, #ffb248);
    height: 50pxx;
    width : 100px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border : 2px solid rgba(33, 68, 72, 0.59);
    text-decoration: none;
}
```